# MKMapView layoutMargins not updating

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit, layoutmargins

I am trying to move center of interests of a MKMapView() with layout margins.
It works but only on init then I can change the value or do anything the map wont update the margins.

The MapView :

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @StateObject var manager: StateManager
    @ObservedObject private var locationManager = LocationManager()
    
    var mapView = MKMapView()
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        print("NEW MAP VIEW")
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        mapView.isRotateEnabled = true
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true

        // This one works well
        mapView.directionalLayoutMargins = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(
            top: 0.0,
            leading: 0.0,
            bottom: 100.0,
            trailing: 0.0
        )

        return mapView
    }

    // ...
}

extension MapView {
    func margins( vertical: CGFloat ) -> some View {
        print("margins", mapView.directionalLayoutMargins.bottom, "<->", vertical)
        mapView.directionalLayoutMargins = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(
            top: 0.0,
            leading: 0.0,
            bottom: vertical,
            trailing: 0.0
        )
        return self
    }

    // ...
}
```

The print occurs and the value (vertical) is correct but the `mapView.directionalLayoutMargins.bottom` return `0.0` despite being stuck at `100.0` from the `init()`.

To complete the vision here is the main view:

```
struct HomeView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var manager: StateManager = StateManager()
    
    @State private var margins: CGFloat = 80.0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            MapView(manager: manager)
                .margins(
                    vertical: manager.verticalMargin
                )
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            SheetView(manager: manager)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

Any idea how to fix this behavior?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake, I have to use the updateUIView method and its view parameter to update any change in the view.

```
func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {
    view.directionalLayoutMargins = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(
        top: 0.0,
        leading: 0.0,
        bottom: newMarginData,
        trailing: 0.0
    )
}
```

And now the view did change.